# Start selenium node with an specific profile (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile, selenium, grid

When I start a standalone selenium test, I can specify the profile path to be used, something like *FirefoxProfile(File("/home/selenium/firefox/1234.MyProfile"))*. However when I use a grid, I don't know how to specify it to the grid. I'd like the selenium node to open with the profile I specify.